# Relationhip between building.cc and building-penetration-loss.cc

Tags: ns-3

Why is there no relation between **building.cc** (located under **src/buildings/model** and **building-penetration-loss.cc** (located under **src/lorawan/model**? They appear independent to each other...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a csv file where building parameters like number of floors, size of building, height. etc are given. I want the building-penetration-loss results from this csv file. At this point, the loss file is running only once and that too it is not integrated with building.cc.

Comment: Based on your comment, I can suggest using two pointers: one for "correlated shadowing" and another for "building penetration loss." Do this then:
shadowing->SetNext(buildingloss). If it doesn't work, I can post a detailed answer.

Comment: I think such a thing is already there in the program...                                                                                             Ptr<CorrelatedShadowingPropagationLossModel> shadowing = CreateObject<CorrelatedShadowingPropagationLossModel> ();
loss->SetNext (shadowing);
      // Add the effect to the channel propagation loss
Ptr<BuildingPenetrationLoss> buildingLoss = CreateObject<BuildingPenetrationLoss> ();
      shadowing->SetNext (buildingLoss);